# Do I need to declare medication every time I cross the border into NZ/Aus?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, australia, health, new-zealand

I have ADHD, and for this I use stimulant medication (similar to Ritalin), which in New Zealand at least holds a class of restriction higher than regular prescribed medications (it requires a Ministry of Health special authority number, which is given by a psychiatrist).

I'm moving to Australia, and I've got a letter from my psychiatrist to give to Australian Customs.

But what I'm wondering is, if I'm flying between New Zealand and Australia regularly, am I going to need to declare my medication every time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Kiwi here, I've moved to Australia.  I fly back and forth reasonably regularly with prescription medication (heart, anxiety, other).

I don't take a letter for the meds, as long as they're in their prescription bottles (with your name) they're fine. Always declare them.

Upside: The 'declare' customs line is often shorter, and they almost always just wave you through.

Downside: Very occasionally you get taken aside for questioning (are the drugs for you? Do you have enough for your stay?), but that's the extent of it.

I've asked a couple of times and the customs officers have always said to declare the medication, both in Australian airports and New Zealand ones.

Comment: Good tip about the 'declare' line often being shorter.